# Why does my Android app icon now show as a black square

Tags: android, appicon

My app icon was displaying correctly. A png file. But somewhere along the way, it has turned into a black square. As far as I know, I haven't changed this since the beginning.

[image]

Here is the app in Android Studio 3.5.2

[image]

Here is how it is specified in my Manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/bd50"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/bd50"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how it works. U should call all the icon's the same only difference is the dpi's. Your phone will choose the right image to display. Now you are forcing bd50 which isn't supported by your phone as dpi.

Comment: Hello Bram. As this is my first app, I am not sure what you are suggesting the solution is. Can you please be specific about what needs to be done?

Comment: I think this documentation will explain it in greater details and is really helpful :).

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-update-the-launcher-icon-for-your-android-app--cms-30624

Follow the steps in the link and u should be set.

Comment: Awesome! That is the piece I was missing.